# Show that $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\left<x^3+1\right>$ is not a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

> Show that $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\left<x^3+1\right>$ is not a field.

It suffice to show that the principal ideal $\left<x^3+1\right>$ is not a maximal ideal.

However, I am unable to get the ball rolling. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: can you write $x^3 + 1$ as a product of two smaller polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$?

Comment: @Chris no( i have no idea how to do this :(

Comment: @Anastasia note that if $f(x) = x^3+1$, then $f(-1) = 0$, so it must be divisible by $x+1$. Can you divide $x^3+1$ by $x+1$?

Comment: I am sure that a certain mechanism for finding a factor has been explained earlier in your course. What is it? What problems stopped you from using it?

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$, you have $f(x)=x^3+1=(x+1)^3=(x+1)(x+1)^2$. Hence $x+1$ is a zero divisor in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\left<x^3+1\right>$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}(x+1)^3&=x^3+3x^2+3x+1\\&\equiv x^3+1\bmod3\end{align}$$hence$$\langle x^3+1\rangle\subsetneq\langle x+1\rangle.$$

Answer (score 2):

We want to factorize $x^3 + 1$ as a product of two polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$. We see that $2$ is a root of this polynomial, so $x^3 + 1$ is a product of $(x - 2)$ and some other quadratic factor. Call it $q(x)$. We can find this quadratic factor by dividing $(x-2)$ into $x^3 + 1$, but we don't need to do that for this problem. We have $x^3 + 1 = (x - 2)q(x)$, which means that $x^3 + 1 \in \langle x - 2 \rangle$. Notice that $\langle x - 2 \rangle$ is a proper ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ containing $x^3 + 1$, and as you have observed, this means that $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle x^3 + 1 \rangle$ is not a field.

Comment: thank u so much!!

Comment: @Anastasia Sure thing. The big takeaway from this is that, in general, when ever you take a polynomial ring and then mod out by a reducible polynomial from that ring, you will obtain a ring that is not a field.